# teradata calling proc with delete table inside

Tags: sql, teradata

I created a stored procedure in which I use a delete table.

The procedure call comes up with error 3523, because the user does not have the right to delete on the table. 
Knowing that the user with whom the table was created is the same user used to call the stored procedure.

Do you have any solution?

```
REPLACE PROCEDURE DATABASE.PROC1 (IN VAR INTEGER, IN SCHEMA VARCHAR(20)) 
BEGIN 
DECLARE nbr_lignes INTEGER; 
DECLARE compteur INTEGER; 
SET compteur=0; 
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DATABASE .TABLE1 INTO nbr_lignes; 
WHILE (compteur<=nbr_lignes) DO 
BEGIN 
CALL DBC.SYSEXECSQL('DELETE FROM DATABASE.TABLE2'); 
...
...
...
SET compteur=compteur+pas; 
END; 
END WHILE; 
END;
```

Comment: Please share the code, which leads to this error.

Comment: If you want to check if the submitting user has the appropriate rights you need to add `SQL SECURITY INVOKER` after the variable declaration and before the BEGIN

Comment: Thanks @dnoeth, I resolve my problem by using "grant all on DATABASE.TABLE2 to public".

Comment: I have another problem: I want to change this expression, to have a parameterized database  for TABLE1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DATABASE.TABLE1 INTO nbr_lignes;                                                      I try to use this expression, but it doesn't work:
SET nbr_total_lignes= CALL DBC.SYSEXECSQL('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM '||SCHEMA||'.TABLE1');
Do you have any idea to retrieve the number of rows in a parameter into a stored procedure?

Comment: `GRANT ALL ON DATABASE.TABLE2 TO PUBLIC` is not the correct solution to this problem. At a minimum, it should certainly trigger a flag on any security audit of your environment.